# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP error.. not really sure why

Tags: swift, xcode

This is where the error is occuring, on the let selectedStudent line,

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if(segue.identifier == "Student_segue") {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let selectedStudent = studentsSorted[indexPath.row]
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! StudentInfoTableViewController
            destination.selectedStudent = selectedStudent
        }
    }

}
```

Here is where I declare studentsSorted and studentArray.

```
typealias studentInfo = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
typealias studentArray = [studentInfo]

let students = StudentRosterModel()
var studentsSorted:studentArray = studentArray()
var selectedRow:Int = 0

func updateStudentInfo(updatedStudent: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

    // replaced the selected row with the updated key/value dictionary

    studentsSorted [selectedRow ] = updatedStudent

    // sort the revised student list
    studentsSorted.sortInPlace{ ($0["last_name"] as? String) < ($1["last_name"] as? String )}

    // reload () tableView to show refreshed view

    tableView.reloadData()


}
```

and this is where I declare selectedStudent,

```
class StudentInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var selectedStudent: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
var delegate: studentUpdate?
```

Really confused here, I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

This error almost print error into console log. I know this error can occurred by out of range error.

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    let selectedStudent = studentsSorted[indexPath.row]
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! StudentInfoTableViewController
    destination.selectedStudent = selectedStudent
}
```

If you declear **self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow** to indexPath and it succeed, then you consider **indexPath.row** is over or under at **studentsSorted**'s size.

Comment: Yeah I discovered that the studentsSorted array has nothing in it, but can't figure out why.

Comment: There are no information about function that insert data to `studentsSorted`. I can find only `updateStudentInfo` that just replace and sort.

Comment: Can you show me how to insert data to `studentsSorted`?